# Docker and React configuration [WINDOWS 10 home and VSCODE]

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, containers

I can't get all the routes of React with docker-compose up command.
docker-compose up => that only allows me to access the default route of the react app. Also, I can access them successfully with local npm run command. Am I missing something, may be in containerisation?
Any ideas why is it happening?

Here's my .yml file

```
version: "3"
services: 
    client:
        build:
            context: ./client
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: fc-client-app
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - /client-app/node_modules
            - .:/client-app
        depends_on: 
            - "server"
    server:
        build:
            context: ./server
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: fc-server-app
        ports: 
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - /server-app/node_modules
            - .:/server-app
```

The problem is with the client service.

And here's my Docker File of Client service:-

```js
FROM node:lts

WORKDIR /usr/src/client-app

ENV PATH /usr/src/client-app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Share your docker-compose.yml

Comment: hey, I've added the yml file.

Comment: Please share your docker files too.

Comment: @AnaLava Can you find something now?

Answer (score 0):

You are exposing port 8080 in your client docker file, but the port specified in the docker-compose is 80 for your client service. And 8080 is for your server service. Please try changing the client port in your docker file.

Comment: That was just trial and error, nevertheless, it worked as I've mentioned while the problem still persists, I can only view my default react route and not the other routes.